# Get currency symbol in Visual Force Email Template

Tags: email, email-template, currency

I need to get currency symbol in visual force email template. 
I want it to be the currency the user is using. 
I check the docs here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm

But don't see anything that will give to me.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you need it as a field formula?

Answer (score 4):

I'm infering from your question that User is the recipient type on your email template. So, how about something utilizing Custom Labels and the ability to access them dynamically, e.g.:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Account">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

   <apex:variable var="isoCode" value="Currency{!recipient.CurrencyISOCode}"/>        
   <apex:variable var="currencySymbol" value="{!$Label[isoCode]}"/>

   Your balance is {!currencySymbol}200.00

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Then you can create a Custom Label CurrencyUSD, CurrencyGBP etc. etc.

Comment: I don't know enough about it, so i've added it as a comment but I wondered if Translation Workbench might also provide some options too?

Comment: I think he needs an image, not a text

Comment: @mast0r - yeah, i noticed that in your answer...I couldn't see a reference to an image, but i did go out on an Xmas party last night so my eyesight is not at its best :)

Comment: For me the party is just tonight :)

Comment: @Phil Hawton first line is <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Daily Digest" recipientType="User" relatedToType="My_Custom_Object__c"> so yes. Howevere your idea gives me: Error: Invalid field CurrencyISOCode for SObject User

Comment: odd...that snippet works perfectly for me (i tested before posting)

Comment: isn't CurrencyISOCode field available in Organization with Multi-Curency enabled?

Comment: Yes it is, I was assuming OP had currency enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For the visualforce page i would take this one:

```
<apex:image value="{!CASE(YourObject.CurrencyIsoCode,'EUR','/img/euro.gif',
                                                     'GBP','/img/gbpfund.gif',
                                                           '/img/default.gif')}"/>
```

Like [Mohith](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/645/mohith-kumar) say's, here is an example with static resource :)

```
<apex:image value="{!CASE(YourObject.CurrencyIsoCode,'EUR',URLFOR($Resource.MyRes,'img/eur.gif'),
                                                     'GBP',URLFOR($Resource.MyRes,'img/gbpfund.gif'),
                                                           URLFOR($Resource.MyRes,'img/default.gif'))}"/>
```

And for the Image field this:

```
IMAGE(CASE({!YourObject.CurrencyIsoCode}, 'EUR', '/img/euro.gif', 
                                          'GBP', '/img/gbpfund.gif',
                                                 '/img/default.gif'), 'image_label')
```

Comment: You may like to show how you can use static resources in your answer :).These images can change in sfdc server without any notice :)